# Tag Audio não funciona no Phonegap

Tags: html, apache-cordova

Tag audio não funciona no Phonegap utilizando o formato AACP, em MP3 funcional normalmente.

```
<audio src="http://107.161.23.70:9984/;stream.nsv" controls autoplay></audio>
```

Alguém sabe o porque disso?

Answer (score 2):

Porque a tag `audio`, por enquanto, suporta somente três formatos de arquivos: `.mp3`, `.wav` e `.ogg`. Há suporte pra reprodução de `.aac` também, mas somente em um container MP4.

[Nessa página](http://textopia.org/androidsoundformats.html) você pode ver alguns testes realizados com esses formatos.
E a [especificação](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-audio-element).